# php and soap with attachment

Tags: php, soap, attachment

I'm new both on PHP and web services. I need to send a file to a web service but I can't find the correct way. The WS is now taking the file as a variable (dh) from a java code like this:

```
QName qnameAttachment = new QName("xsd:ASCII");
call.registerTypeMapping(DataHandler.class, qnameAttachment, JAFDataHandlerSerializerFactory.class, JAFDataHandlerDeserializerFactory.class);
DataHandler dh = new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(this.idh));
```

then the dh variable is sent to the WS (SOAP call) and the WS generates this XML tag:

```
<dh href="cid:2643CE40EEF7B2F167ED283AE8BC6326" xsi:type="xsd:ASCII"/>
```

I'm now trying to write a code in PHP which is able to the same thing but I can't find the correct solution. I tried to encode the file by means of "base64_encode" function:

```
 $dh = base64_encode($tarfile);
```

$dh assume a value similar to "cnwicubnweiv87723re2".
Then I tried to pass the $dh variable to the WS as a normal string but this is the result:

```
<dh> cnwicubnweiv87723re2 </dh>
```

The WS does not recognize the variable as an attribute for the tag .
I clearly wrong to send the $dh as normal string and I don't know how to pass it to let the WS know to use it as an attribute.

Can someone help me please?